# Match Two CSVs Based on Pattern Matching in One Column

Tags: python, bash, shell, join, awk

I have two CSV files in these formats:

```
==

FirstName | LastName | Email
Steven | Smith | stevesmith1@gmail.com
Jane | Brown | jb155@yahoo.com
Paul | Gibson | paulgibbs@outlook.com

==

ID | FirstName | LastName | IncompleteEmail
1028332982 | Steven | Smith | s*****1@g*l.com
1028820233 | Jane | Brown | j******n@yahoo.com
934943823 | Paul | Gibson | p*****s@h****l.com

==
```

I would like to match between the two CSV files on this basis - if the `FirstName` and `LastName` are the same, the `Email` in the first CSV matches the pattern of the `IncompleteEmail` in the second CSV, the output should be created containing `ID | Email`

In the example above, the output would look like this:

```
ID | Email
1028332982 | stevesmith1@gmail.com
```

The reason for this is because "Steve" and "Smith" are the same in both CSVs, and the `IncompleteEmail` pattern matches the Email. The other inputs do not match as the `IncompleteEmail` pattern does not match the email.

I have previously used a `join` script (e.g. `join -i -t '|' -j 1 -o 2.2,2.3 1.txt 2.txt > out.txt`) to process similar files, but I don't know how to modify the join script to work with a pattern instead of an exact match. I'm aware that a similar approach might be possible with AWK, but I'm open to suggestions.

Need something that can work with large inputs (two CSVs of 10 million+ rows each).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain how the `IncompleteEmail` patterns work? (And CSV? Your samples are |-delimited, not comma delimited...)

Comment: The word `pattern` is extremely vague and ambiguous and so best avoided. Having said that I don't see a regexp match nor a char-for-char match with `*` being a wildcard, nor anything else I'm familiar with so - what exactly are those "patterns"? And are there **really** blank chars on each side of every `|` in your data? If not then fix your example to look like your real data.

Comment: This was actually my question, and now the real data doesn't have spaces either side of the |'s - I put these in to make it appear clearer.

Comment: Don't post sample data that doesn't look like your real data trying to make it clearer as it has the completely opposite effect and you end up getting a solution that either doesn't work or isn't optimal for your real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want any repetition of `*`s to be treated the same way that `.*` is treated in a regexp and every other RE metacharacter (e.g. `.`) to be treated literally and that `^` can't occur in an email address:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=" [|] "; OFS=" | " }
FNR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
}
{ name = $(f["FirstName"]) FS $(f["LastName"]) }
NR==FNR {
    name2fullEmail[name] = $(f["Email"])
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    print "ID", "Email"
    next
}
name in name2fullEmail {
    fullEmail = name2fullEmail[name]
    partEmail = $(f["IncompleteEmail"])
    gsub(/./,"[&]",partEmail)
    gsub(/[[][*][]]/,".*",partEmail)
    if (fullEmail ~ "^"partEmail"$") {
        print $(f["ID"]), fullEmail
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
ID | Email
1028332982 | stevesmith1@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider your first `csv` file as `df1`, whilst the second `csv` as `df2`. So, you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df_new = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['FirstName','LastName'], how='inner')
mails = []
regex = "((\w{1})\D.*(\w{1}\@\w{1})\D.*(\w{1}[\.]\D.+)"
for d in range(len(df_new)):
    inmail = re.findall(regex,df_new.iloc[d]["IncompleteEmail"])
    commail = re.findall(regex,df_new.iloc[d]["Email"])
    if inmail == commail:
        mails.append([df_new.iloc[d]['ID'],df_new.iloc[d]["Email"]])
pd.DataFrame(mails, columns=["ID","Email"])
```

Output:

```
           ID                  Email
0  1028332982  stevesmith1@gmail.com
```

Comment: But the output is incorrect because the second and third outputs you've listed here don't match between the Email and IncompleteEmail

Comment: You can see it above.

Comment: Updated. Check again!

Answer (score 0):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk -F" [|] " -v OFS="|" '   # set field separators
NR==FNR {                      # process first file
    a[$1 OFS $2]=$3            # hash email, use name as key
    next
}
((i=$2 OFS $3) in a) {         # process second file
    gsub(/\./,"\\.",$4)        # escaping:      . -> \.
    gsub(/\*+/,".*",$4)        #           *{1,n} -> .*
    if(FNR==1 || a[i]~$4)      # if header record or regex match
        print $1,a[i]          # then output
}' file1 file2                 # mind the order
```

Output:

```
ID|Email
1028332982|stevesmith1@gmail.com
```

While processing the second file `file2` `gsub(/\*+/,".*",$4)` tries to make the emails regex *ish*: `s*****1@g*l.com` -> `s.*1@g.*l\.com`. Provided sample data did not have any other regex metachars than `*` and `.` but others (like `+`) should probably be escaped too to avoid false matches but I'm not really sure if you have special meaning for them like you had for `*`.

Also, it won't tolerate duplicated names in `file1`. Last instance wins.